# Testing Core Data Entities Logic

Tags: ios, core-data

I have to update the complete code because now I am using a different way. In my unit test project I setup the CoreDataStack as shown below:

```
final class BudgetAppTests: XCTestCase {

    private var persistentStoreContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    private var coreDataProvider: CoreDataProvider!
    
    override func setUp() {
        
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BudgetAppModel", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize managed object model.")
        }
        
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize managed object model from file at \(modelURL)")
        }
        
        persistentStoreContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "BudgetAppModel", managedObjectModel: mom)
        persistentStoreContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        
        persistentStoreContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error {
                fatalError("Failed to initialize the store \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

My test is not failing because assertions are not passing and also it throws weird type mismatch error when I try to fetch the data.

```
  func testCalculateBudgetSpent() {
        
        let context = persistentStoreContainer.viewContext
        
        // create the budget
        let budget = Budget(context: context)
        budget.title = "Vacation"
        budget.limit = 200
        budget.dateCreated = Date()
        
        // create an expense
        let expense = Expense(context: context)
        expense.title = "Burger"
        expense.quantity = 2
        expense.amount = 10
        expense.tags = []
        
        budget.addToExpenses(expense)
        
        try! context.save()
        
        // test fails // budget.spend is always 0
        XCTAssertEqual(180, budget.spent)
        
        // fetch budget
        let budgetRequest: NSFetchRequest<Budget> = Budget.fetchRequest()
        
        // THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS ERROR
        // Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
        //Expected Budget but found Budget
        let results = try! context.fetch(budgetRequest)
        print(results)
    }
```

Budget+Extensions.swift

```
extension Budget {
    
    var spent: Double {
        
        guard let expenses = expenses as? Set<Expense> else { return 0 }
        return expenses.reduce(0) { total, expense in
            return total + (expense.amount * Double(expense.quantity)) 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not work for anything? The test is unable to load the models. This may be because models (momd) are in main project and not in test project.

Comment: I edited the question completely to highlight my current issues.